# How to calculate sum of distinct in SSRS

Tags: grouping, sybase, ssrs-2012, distinct-values

[image]

After grouping country, i am getting total as 150. But as per requirement it should be 120. How to achieve this??
Tried =SUM(Fields!Amt.Value,"GroupCtry") --> Gives an error.
Tried SUM(DISTINCT(Amt) at database level, still no success. Using Syabse ASE.

Any leads, on how to do this??

TIA!

Comment: "Gives an error"  What error?

Comment: The Value expression for the text box 
‘Textbox2’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  
The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either 
the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or 
the name of a dataset.

Comment: This error means that "GroupCtry" is not the name of a dataset in your report.   Maybe you have a typo in the name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239408/sum-of-distinct-in-ssrs